# Windows Phone 7 Image Button

Tags: windows-phone-7, imagebutton

I need to create an Image Button for my application like web-oriented style.
I have an image 20x20 pixel and want an image button with the same dimension of the image.

I tried to set this inside my xaml but it doesn't work:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" Click="AddtoFavorite_Click" Width="20" Height="20"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
   <Button.Content>
      <Image Source="/MyNamespace;component/images/star_yellow.png" Margin="0" Width="20" Height="20" />
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

What is wrong?

---

### SOLUTION

I found the best solution is:

```
<Image Source="/MyNamespace;component/images/star_yellow.png" ManipulationStarted="Image_ManipulationStarted" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: I think there is a flaw to this solution. The trouble is if someone swipes the view starting on your button, usually the button click will not register. However the way you've implmented it, the button will be considered clicked. This is counterintuative to how users expect the phone to work and may cause a confusing user experience.

I think you're much better off using a button but styling it to render as an image.

Answer (score 20):

I don't see particular errors in your code but I don't have the tools right now to test it ans see why it fails.

However you can create a VisualBrush with your image and use it as background for your Button:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="xyz.png"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Most Backgrounds are of type Brush, so you can use SolidColorBrush, LinearGradientBrush, ImageBrush, etc. You are not limited to colors.

Comment: Hi, I have an image 20x20 and want the button 20x20 like image.
With the solution you posted is not possible. Which properties I have to set? i tried Padding, Margin, etc, but nothing...

Comment: You should then tell us exactly what is not working. Keep in mind that according to the UI guidelines the minimum size for a "touchable" object is 26x26 with a 34x34 hit target area.

Comment: My answer lets you set the size of the button to whatever you want. It's replacing the way the button draws to make it draw an image instead of the standard button.

Comment: @FrancescoDeVittori I'm having the same issue - I have 100x100 images that I am trying to map to 62x62 images to buttons and this solution shrinks them to ~38x38.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is the following:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Template>
         <ControlTemplate>
              <Image .... />
         </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Using manipulation started will result in subtly non-standard behaviour. On most buttons if you click on it but then drag off, the button click will not fire. However, if you use ManipulationStarted it will fire immediately.

The best way to manage these design time considerations is to use Expression Blend. In blend you can right click on the button and edit the template through the design tools, which makes knowing how to edit the xaml less important. It's really worth the effort to learn to use Blend.

Answer (score 4):

This is old but I thought I would offer what I thought was a better solution here. Some of these solutions want you to replace the button with an image, or the background with an imagebrush. That's fine except it also surrounds the image with the normal button style, a black or white box (depending on your theme).

This solution lets you use an image as the button itself while maintaining the complete fidelity of a button but without having to subclass an object like the link by SilverGeek.

First, create a new style (either in your App.xaml or your page resources)

```
<Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="StartButtonImage" Source="/Images/YourImageFile.png"/>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                    Content=""/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Now, just create a button anywhere using that style:

```
<Button Style={StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}/>
```

And add click events or whatever else you want. The button will take on the entire style of the image.

Answer (score 1):

The **Button** control can take most controls as its content (not just text), so you don't need an "image button" - instead, you simply need to put an Image control inside your Button like so:

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="http://www.richmondwiki.org/images/search-button.png"></Image>
</Button>
```

This approach (as opposed to using an ImageBrush for the Button background) means that you don't have to worry about or hardcode the sizes of the Image/Button - WP7 will handle this for you.

Using the provided Button control instead of hooking into the manipulation events is recommended, so that you won't have to worry about things like having appropriate margins for touch targets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image as the background for the button, or if you want to do it as content, in theory it should work inside a stackpanel.

Comment: Background property of Button accept only colors. Can you post syntax to me? Thanks.

Comment: You can see in this post both syntax for using an ImageBrush as the Background and a link to Peter Torr's post showing use of a StackPanel. Admitedly this was in response to Hyperlink button, and Richard's original post showing setting the image as the content may in fact work for Button despite the observations I made for why it wasn't working for HyperlinkButton at the time.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/6d6449dc-7a87-4e8e-bdd6-e01afca85414

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use a Button.

You can hook the MouseLeftButtonUp event on the Image control.

```
 <Image
            Source='blue02.png'
            Width='26'
            Height='26'
            Margin='5'
            MouseLeftButtonUp='Image_MouseLeftButtonUp' />
```