# What is the best way to create an Image Button in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, imagebutton

In Android we can use a selector defined in an .xml file. In Windows Phone, how we can implement it in a fast way?

Comment: You could try [Francesco De Vittori's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4303142/122005)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image into the Button's Content property.

```
<Button>
<Button.Content>
<Grid>
<Image Name="Normal" Source="Resources/Image.png"/>
</Grid>
</Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the reply. Yes, your solution is a valid one, but it is just part of what I'm looking for. My problem is when the button gets clicked, pressed, holded, and so on. For each case, we need a specific type of event handler. In Android, the selector does the tricky.

Comment: There are various events you can hook on (tap, double tap from the top of my head).

Comment: @mthama - So you know what you need to do.  What exactly is your question?